# What is the correct syntax within a Sunspot.search block to return Posts which match an array of category_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm using Sunspot 1.3.0 in a Rails project.

```
Post.search do
  with(:category_ids, [1, 3, 5])
end
```

will match Posts with a category of 1, 3, or 5.

What is the correct syntax to match posts with categories of exactly 1, 3 **and** 5?

E.g. Posts where
category_ids = [1] - doesn't match
category_ids = [1, 3] - doesn't match
category_ids = [1, 3, 5] - **does** match
category_ids = [1, 3, 5, 7] - doesn't match

I tried

```
with(:category_ids).equal_to([1,3,5])
```

but this gives me the following error:
undefined method `gsub' for ["1", "3", "5"]:Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up using "all_of" to solve this problem.
In case it helps anyone else, this is what I did:

```
with(:category_ids).all_of([1,3,5])
```

This will match Posts categories of [1,3,5], but also Posts with any additional categories, e.g. [**0**,1,3,5,**7**] will match, too.

Once Sunspot had returned its result set, I filtered out the Posts which didn't match exactly.

This does what I want, but I'd hoped there was a more concise way to do this.